# Stuck at transferring ssh keys to SSH server

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

When I try to access VM through ssh, it stuck at transferring ssh keys to SSH servers.

Already checked the solutions mentioned at:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/zJS0qFFQYlM

but they didn't work.

The messages are shown on the screen when I try to access VM through ssh.

> The key transfer to project metadata is taking an unusually long time. Transferring instead to instance metadata may be faster, but will transfer the keys only to this VM. If you wish to SSH into other VMs from this VM, you will need to transfer the keys accordingly.
>
> Click here to transfer the key to instance metadata. Note that this setting is persistent and needs to be disabled in the Instance Details page once enabled.
> You can drastically improve your key transfer times by migrating to OS Login.

Comment: Did you find any solution?